# Smarty: Same row getting displayed more than once

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table, smarty

Here's my PHP code (A query which returns rows having 2 columns: ReportId and MailingFrequency):

```
while($x=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
    {
    $X[0] = $x['ReportId'];
    $X[1] = $x['MailingFrequency'];
    $X[2] = 'Stop Subscription';
    $this->smarty->assign("X", $X);
    }
```

My HTML code (To display data from smarty variable X):

```html
{section name=index loop = $X}   
          <tr> 
          <td width="25%">{$X[0]}</td>
          <td width="35%">{$X[1]}</td>
          <td width="40%"><a href="../webadmin/stopsubscription" id="StopSubscription" style="color: #CC0000">{$X[2]}</a></td>
      </tr>
```

Now, in the case dataset has only one row of format (ReportId,MailingFrequency) e.g.(1,'Saturday'), it is displayed correctly. But, in case of multiple rows, only the last row is displayed. 
How to display all the rows in the html table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code X value was constantly overwritten:

```
$list = array();
while($x=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
    $list[] = array(
        'report_id' => $x['ReportId'],
        'mailing frequency' => $x['MailingFrequency'],
        'text' => 'Stop Subscription'
    );
}
$this->smarty->assign(compact('list'));
```

View:

```
{foreach from=list item=val}   
  <tr> 
      <td width="25%">{$val.report_id}</td>
      <td width="35%">{$val.mailing_frequency}</td>
      <td width="40%"><a href="../webadmin/stopsubscription" id="StopSubscription" style="color: #CC0000">{$val.text}</a></td>
  </tr>
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should fix your PHP code:

```php
$reports = array();
while($x = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
    $reports[] = array($x['ReportId'], $x['MailingFrequency'], 'Stop Subscription');
}

$this->smarty->assign('reports', $reports);
```

And you should use {foreach} in Smarty:
http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl

```html
{foreach from=$reports item=report}
    <tr> 
      <td width="25%">{$report[0]}</td>
      <td width="35%">{$report[1]}</td>
      <td width="40%"><a href="../webadmin/stopsubscription" id="StopSubscription" style="color: #CC0000">{$report[2]}</a></td>
    </tr>
{/foreach}
```

Hope I helped. :)

Comment: Oh, you were faster :D

Comment: Haha, sorry for that. :D

Comment: @RuchirSharma check in phpdocs for compact. It might help you send variables to templates.